# ModuleNotFoundError: though the required modules are installed already

Tags: python, module, dependencies, dependency-management, python-venv

I have installed all required libraries in venv, as you can see below.

```
Package            Version
------------------ --------
blinker            1.7.0
Bootstrap-Flask    2.2.0
certifi            2024.2.2
charset-normalizer 3.3.2
click              8.1.7
colorama           0.4.6
dominate           2.9.1
Flask              3.0.2
Flask-Bootstrap    3.3.7.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy   3.1.1
Flask-WTF          1.2.1
greenlet           3.0.3
idna               3.6
itsdangerous       2.1.2
Jinja2             3.1.3
MarkupSafe         2.1.5
pip                23.1.2
requests           2.31.0
setuptools         65.5.0
SQLAlchemy         2.0.27
typing_extensions  4.10.0
urllib3            2.2.1
visitor            0.1.3
Werkzeug           3.0.1
WTForms            3.0.1
```

Yet, the below 3 imports are throwing ModuleNotFoundError.

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String, Float
```